# SSDs show up in AHCI mode but not RAID mode

Tags: ssd, bios, raid

We have a problem with our motherboard where the SSDs installed (there is no M.2 installed, just 2 SSDs) are detected when the SATA mode in BIOS is set to AHCI, but disappear with no way to set up a RAID when the SATA mode is changed to RAID.

From [this Tom's Hardware link](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/sata-drives-not-showing-up-anywhere.3389882/) they said if an M.2 was installed the SATA 5 and 6 ports on the motherboard could not be used in RAID mode.  We are actually plugged into those ports (the side ports), but there is no M.2 installed in the unit.

How can we get the SSDs detected in RAID mode so that we can properly set up a RAID1?  According to another site, the RaidXpert2 utility should be found under Advanced --> SATA Configuration, but no such utility exists.

Motherboard: Asus TUF B450-Plus Gaming

Comment: Is the bios up to date ?

Comment: There was an option to enable the ethernet controller in BIOS and check for updates from within BIOS.  When I did that, there were no updates available.